# What should I use with proxies? Sockets, http.client, pycurl, or anything else?

Tags: python, python-3.x, socks, pycurl, http.client

Okay so basically, I'm writing a piece of code that heavily depends on speed,

```
headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+jtw,
        }
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.minecraftservices.com")
        conn.request("PUT", "/minecraft/profile/name/"+user, headers=headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        status_code = response.status
        resp = response.read().decode("utf-8")
```

I tried http.client, but apparently they don't support proxies, I want similar/same speed, and it needs to support proxies, my question now is.. what should I use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`http.client` does support proxies, see

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.set_tunnel

Concerning speed, a proxied HTTP request time is dominated by waiting for network responsens, so the various different overheads in `curl`, `Socket` or `http.client` are irrelevant, they will all have the same speed.

Comment: I don't quite get what that would look like, like this maybe?
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(choice(proxies), 80)
conn.set_tunnel("api.minecraftservices.com")
conn.request("PUT", "/minecraft/profile/name/"+user, headers=headers)

Comment: Yes it looks right